# Converting a number to a string in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a matrix to a text file. 
The first element of my matrix is a number (an object id) which has several digits. The first digit can be a zero (eg 023512, 146498 etc).

To write the file, I have a loop:

```
objectID = [023512, 023534, 112512, 063512, 223512];
fSpec = ['%s', '\n'];
fID = fopen('file', 'w');
for k=1:5
    to_write = [num2str(objectID(k)) ',' 'l'];
    fprintf(fID, fSpec, to_write);
end
fclose(fID)
```

In this example, I get the file

23512,l
23534,l
112512,l
63512,l
223512,l

The 0 have disappeared.

I tried to use %d in the fSpec ['%d' '%s' '%s' '\n], but in that case, I get a warning:  Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to character. The zero is still removed and everything is written in the same line.

Is there any way to convert a number to a string without truncating the zero?

Thank you

Comment: Where does `objectID` come from? `objectID = [023512, 023534, 112512, 063512, 223512];` won't have leading zeros becuase they're numbers. you could do `objectID = ['023512', '023534', '112512', '063512', '223512'];` or if it's a fixed digit length then you could pad with zeros afterwards?

Comment: It's a fixed digit length so I'll pad with zeros. Thanks

Comment: @bigTree I think you should then use my solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
objectID = 023512;
oStr     = num2str(objectID , '%06d');
```

Comment: '%06d' for leading zeros

'%6d' for leading whitespace

Answer (score 1):

What about using zero-padding from [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) (assuming IDs are always 6 digit numbers)

```
objectID = [023512, 023534, 112512, 063512, 223512];
fSpec = '%06d,l\n'; % Note the %06d here!
fID = fopen('file', 'w');
for k=1:5
    to_write = objectID(k);
    fprintf(fID, fSpec, to_write);
end
fclose(fID)
```